# Copy a file from one computer to many computers?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using windows 7. I need to write a batch file to copy a file (can be any extension) from the one computer to many computers. How can i do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy c:\tmp\localfile.txt \\computer1\c$\tmp
copy c:\tmp\localfile.txt \\computer2\c$\tmp
```

... and so on

Not elegant, but should be working

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. i dont want to repeat the copy command as many times as the number of computers. is it possible to keep all computer names in a text file and iterating? Thanx!

Comment: @user755806: Search for how iterate over lines of a text file then. There are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow.